# FFmpeg In Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia Gpu Acceleration

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, ffmpeg, codecs

I recently tried to integrate NVENC to FFmpeg but the documentation has all messed me up.

Is cuda toolkit needed for compiling ffmpeg with NVENC support? If yes cuda toolkit is available only of Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, can I use  cuda toolkit for Ubuntu 18.04 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Looking for a proper guide.

Comment: For 20.04 it looks like the nv-codec-headers are used with the stock FFmpeg so no extra packages should be required. cuda toolkit is not required if you simply want to use `h264_nvenc` and friends...

Comment: @andrew.46 i tried it yesterday , its working very well

Comment: So you have solved your own question :)

Comment: @andrew.46 yes after searching for a couple of hours yesterday

Comment: Can you post the answer please? Stock Ubuntu 20.04 with 1650 cannot use ffmpeg with nvenc support somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by finding whether the graphics-card is working properly in your system by typing the following command `nvidia-smi`. If that command gave a proper output
you can use hardware acceleration without any other third-party plugins.